# Unable to get accurate location from GPS

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, google-latitude

I am unable to get accurate Latitude , longitude from GPS .. I need to get The location of the small blue pointer(My Current Location) on Google maps in Android ... but I am getting the Location where Red marker is placed manually.
Here is the ScreenSnap..
[image]
Here is the code for getting the location of red marker.

```
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
                if(isGPSEnabled) {
                if(location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    if(locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                        if(location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You are not requesting your location from a GPS device as your subject suggest. Use a gps device to determine your position.

Comment: sory i pasted only one piece of code ... i edited the post with second function which takes location from GPS...

Comment: I just need to know that ... is there any way (function) to get the location of the built in "blue point" marked on map ? because it always be marked on perfect location point.

Comment: Use only code for gps. If it does not give exact position then buy a better device.

Answer (score 0):

Use  ['FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates'](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) to get current location. The fused location provider is one of the location APIs in Google Play Services. It manages the underlying location technology and provides a simple API so that you can specify requirements at high level. Also, don't forget to enable device GPS.

Here's a sample demo app for FusedLocationApi, it shows how to use the said API: https://github.com/codepath/android-google-maps-demo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/MapDemoActivity.java

Comment: yes i tried that but in the first it give me the last location.. doest giving me the current location ... thats why i switch to this piece of code again.!